# Green's Theorem on a union of closed curve (i.e., two triangles)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

So there is a particular Calculus III problem regarding a piece-wise function that has been bothering me a lot lately. G is a moving particle that goes from **a1 (-1,0)** to **a2 (1,1)** to **a3 (1,-1)** to **a4 (2,0)** and then *back to* **a1 (1,1)** again.

So we can see that this curve makes two nice, same-sized triangles which are connected. Now, we know that **Green's Theorem can be used to find the work of a curve that is simple, closed.** But, we see that this curve *crosses* itself. Does this mean that this has transformed to a ‘complex curve’ and Green's Theorem can no longer be applied here?

However, I was wondering if we can treat it as a **union of two different simple curves** ‘triangle A’ (clockwise, hence -ve) and ‘triangle B’ (anti-clockwise, hence +ve) and use Green's Theorem to find the work done here by a force field **[ F = {sinπ(x-y),  cosπ(x+y)}]** in this moving particle along the curve G? Then use the basic properties of double integrals to break it up and evaluate it?

Comment: You can split it into a line integral from $a1$ to $a2$ and then apply green's theorem for your closed curve (triangle) starting and ending at $a2$ which is oriented counterclockwise.